# Добавление сразу нескольких элементов в массив python за один раз

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть проблемы следующая: 
Есть неопределенное количество чисел, уже записанных в столбец.
Нужно за одну операцию Ctrl+c/ctrl+v добавить их в массив и завершить заполнение массива.

Чтобы было понятнее, опишу ситуацию. Есть неопределенное количество участников экзамена, каждому из которых были выставлены баллы. Так, имея, например, exel столбик с баллами (строго нефиксированного количества), необходимо скопировать столбик, вставить его в уже IDE и произвести дальнейшие операции с массивом (правильнее - со списком).

Comment: Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas - он как раз предназначен для обработки табличных данных

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @tutankhamun Вот, рассмотрите этот код. Он, в целом, простейший, но со вставкой элементов в массив есть проблема https://imgur.com/a/N3kekqW

Comment: В чем именно проблема? В том что вы вставляете туда просто столбец чисел, а python требует наличия запятых?

Comment: @tutankhamun Проблема не в этом. Я до сих пор не придумал, как вставить все числа разом. Если использовать stdin, то как правильно завершить ввод? Если без него, то как при вводе https://imgur.com/a/F1Tr3RW сюда сделать так, чтобы только за одну операцию ctrl+v питон сразу занес все числа в массив (неважно, в строчку с запятыми или без, все равно массив печататься не будет).

Comment: @MaxU это перебор, анализ данных для такой простенькой задачки не самое хорошее решение, но спасибо)

Comment: Пример кода бы, а то не очень понятно. Вообще добавить несколько чисел в списко за раз можно c помощью метода `extend`

Comment: Действительно, ничего непонятно. Вставить в IDE  - вставляте текст и обрабатывайте. Или вы хотите функцию чтения из clipboard? или что?

Comment: Если "exel столблик" открывать в Опенофисе, то там можно прямо написать скрпит который будет работать с выделенным диапазоном данных

Comment: Насчет использования stdin - тоже непонятно, что не получается. Вставили столбец в текстовый файл и скармливаете его питону